# generate dynamic instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails view, collection of items

```
<% @useful_types.each do |useful_type| %>
```

processes a number of operations

```
  <% @init = @valid_mos.first %>
```

These operations need to be held over as unique values in the same view to be used in furteh context.  However I cannot fine the syntax to allow a processed string to generate an instance variable

```
<% @#{useful_type[2..-1]}_code = @init.code %>
```

is not allowed `@#`.  Is there a succinct way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `instance_variable_set`:

```
<% instance_variable_set("@#{useful_type[2..-1]}_code", @init.code) %>
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling onto this, there is the getter method to accompany that `instance_variable_get` . Neat.